# Grunt not running any tasks except for watch

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, npm, bower

I'm trying to build a website with Bootstrap, using Grunt to run tasks. I have been trying to figure out why my gruntfile does not seem to be running any tasks except for 'watch', but I can't seem to find the answer. No errors show up either. In terminal, time-grunt will show the execution time (although no tasks are executed) and then it would say 'Waiting....' which means watch is running. Could someone shed some light on what I've done wrong in my gruntfile? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    //time
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    style: 'compressed',
                },

                files: {
                    'assets/css/style.css' : 'assets/scss/style.scss',
                }
            }
        },

        copy: {
            scripts: {
                cwd: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/',
                expand: true,
                src: [
                    'jquery.min.js',
                    ],
                dest: 'assets/js/',
                filter: 'isFile',
            }
        },

        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';',
            },
            js: {
                src: [
                    'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
                    'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js',
                    'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js',
                    'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js',
                    'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js',
                    'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js',
                    'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js',
                ],
                dest: 'assets/js/bootstrap.js',
            },
            sass: {
                src: [
                    'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss',
                    'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/**/*.scss'
                ],
                dest: 'assets/scss/style.scss'
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: false,
            },

            my_target: {
                files: {
                    'assets/css/style.min.css' : ['assets/css/style.css'],
                    'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' : ['assets/js/bootstrap.js']
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            gruntfile: {
                files: 'Gruntfile.js',
                tasks: ['jshint:gruntfile'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            src: {
                files: ['assets/js/*.js', 'assets/scss/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['default'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },

        jshint: {
            all: ['Gruntfile.js', 'assets/**/*.js']
        },


    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

    grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass', 'copy', 'concat', 'uglify']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch', 'jshint']);
};
```

Comment: have you tried "grunt buld"? this will invoke the build task

Comment: In addition to the comment from Harikrishnan, `grunt` will run the `default` task which does watch and jshint. I believe you should move the `watch` to the end of the array or it blocks the other tasks from executing.

Comment: okay, thank you both so much. I typed 'grunt build' into terminal, and also put 'watch' at the end of the array and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Your tasks names and orders were a bit mixed up, here are 3 points to fully fix it - and provide StackOverflow with an answer to the question:

- `watch` should always be the last task to run, as it does not end. So:

  ```
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'watch']);
  ```
- if you want to run a task (like `build` by just calling grunt, you have to put it in your default task, so:

  ```
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'build', 'watch']);
  ```
- your watch task must not launch a watch task itself, so `watch.src` should not call `default` (as default includes watch):

  ```
  watch: {
      gruntfile: {
          files: 'Gruntfile.js',
          tasks: ['jshint:gruntfile'],
          options: {
              livereload: true
          }
      },
      src: {
          files: ['assets/js/*.js', 'assets/scss/*.scss'],
          tasks: ['jshint', 'build'],
          options: {
              livereload: true
          }
      }
  },
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Clears up my understanding of how to run the default and build tasks.